# Azure as SAML 2.0 Service Provider

Tags: azure, saml-2.0

I'm looking for help for configuring Azure as SAML2.0 service provider. I have a SAML 2.0 identity provider which i need to integrate with Azure so that applications which leverage Azure can be Single signed on to using my Identity Provider.

I have tried creating an identity provider in Azure Access Control Service ,but seems like it currently supports WS-Federation identity provider only. It does not have any option for adding SAML 2.0 identity provider.

Is there a way to add SAML2.0 identity provider in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - Azure AD is always the IDP.

If you want to add your SAML application as an SP, refer [Configuring single sign-on to applications that are not in the Azure Active Directory application gallery](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-custom-apps/).

Answer (score 1):

azure can work as sp with external IDP
it can be configured from azure extenral identities

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).